# WPF - RadRichTextBox Style of character at caret position

Tags: c#, wpf

is it possibility to take font size of character in caret/cursor position after click mouse somewhere?

After searching I can take caret position, or default FontSize in Document attribute, but I couldn't find answer of my question.

Comment: When you say "take", do you mean "change", "change temporarily (whilst cursor is there)", or "find"?

Comment: I want to know which fontsize is set.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentEditingStyle property should work for you. For example, if you want to get the font style of the curent character, you could use the following:

```
var fontStyle = this.radRichTextBox.CurrentEditingStyle.SpanProperties.FontStyle;
```

Note that this would not work the same when there is selection. In this case, the value returned will be Bold, for example, only if *all* of the selected text is bold.